# bootstrap modal: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am getting the above error message with bootstrap modal.

**Whats happening:**

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.btn-red').on('click', function () {

        var var1 = jQuery(this).data('target');

        jQuery('#cancel_form_display').load(url + var1, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "success") {

                jQuery(var1).modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

I am using several js/jQuery plugins. So I am using jQuery in no-conflict mode. using *'jQuery'* instead of *'$'*. When this function is called I am getting 'undefined is not a function' in line:

```
jQuery(var1).modal('show');
```

**What have I tried?**

1. Followed the suggestion on other posts with the same issue and made sure that bootstrap.min.js is loaded.
2. changed the function line to:

   `jQuery(var1).modal({show:true});`
3. Changed the order of loading of plugin files.

**More Information**
I am also getting this error: 'Cannot set property 'display' of undefined' associated with prototype.js
This is with the method: 'show'

I am loading the js files in this order:

1. jQuery-lib/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
2. prototype.js
3. bootstrap.min.js

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I assume you've checked what `var1` is at that point, and also tried to run `jQuery(var1).modal('show');` separately, outside this click method? (obviously with a selector value instead of var1)

Comment: I've tested the above function as it is in a separate html file. i works fine. When I tried to copy the same into my webapp it gives me the above error

Comment: you can do something like this...or modify using this     http://jsfiddle.net/qrq7cez0/

Comment: I'm loading the content from another page.

Comment: are there any other console errors before you click on any `.btn-red` link?

Comment: actually I'm upgrading my webapp from old codeigniter version to new one. there are 3-4 errors. But I guess they are not related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in your code is :

```
 jQuery('#'+var1).modal('show');
```

You are calling modal you need to pass # sign before your variable or if you have set # sign in target attribute then no need to write it.

Comment: Thanks. this solves the above issue. But I'm getting new error - 'unrecognized expression: ##cancel_form'. I have named my data('target') like this: #cancel_form. so I guess your line adds one more '#' to it.